# Saving a file to your own android application

Tags: android, android-file, apk

When My application is running I want to capture some information and save this to a folder in my application rather than to the device. I have read online that it is not possible to save a file to your assets or res directory. However would it be possible to save it to another file in your application?I had a look at Shared Preferences but that seems to be only for Key Value pairs.

Comment: You can save raw files to internal memory that are accessible only to your app on unrooted devices. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: "save this to a folder in my application rather than to the device" - is your application not running on a device?

Comment: You seem a bit confused by my question Justin. Maybe you should read it again.

Comment: Thing is: your app is either on the SD card or the internal storage (or it can't run on Dalvik.) Therefore, by definition, anything you save (even if you could, somehow, alter your apk programmatically) would be on the SD or the internal memory.

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Writing to internal storage with MODE_PRIVATE should handle what I think you want..

Answer (score 0):

You cannot store the files in the Assets or the Raw folder at run time.
Instead if you have image/video/audio/textual files you can store the files in your SD card and store the path of those files in your file in Database or shared preferences.

Comment: No I don't want the application to access the SD Card/Internal Storage at all. Is this possible?

Comment: You can not store other than internal/SD card storage.

Answer (score 0):

After installation each application creates a storage located in '/data/data/com.your.app.package.name'. Save whatever you want in that place.

Comment: So would this be the way i would access it:                                   File newxmlfile = new File("/data/data/mypackagename"
    + "/new.xml");
  newxmlfile.mkdir();

Comment: Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() and so on.

Comment: Thats how you store something on your internal storage which is NOT what Im looking for